# nodejs array items are Promise "{ <pending> }"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to download images. So I need asynchronous process. And my code snipped like that:

```
 Template.findOne({ templateId: template_id }).exec()
        .then(template => {
            if (imageURLs.length !== template.requiredImages.count) {
                res.status(422).json({
                    status: "Fail",
                    message: "This template needed " + template.requiredImages.count + " image. But received " + imageURLs.length
                })
            } else {
                return template;
            }
        })
        .then(template => {

            function naming(length) {
                var result = '';
                var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
                var charactersLength = characters.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
                        charactersLength));
                }
                return result;
            }
            var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
                request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
                    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
                    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

                    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename + '.' + res.headers['content-type'].split('/')[1])).on('close', callback);
                });
            };


            var imagePaths = [];

            for (const imageURL of imageURLs) {
                imagePaths.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let filename = __dirname + '/../../../downloads/' + naming(6)
                    download(imageURL, filename, function (data, err) {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        else resolve(filename)
                    });
                }))

            }

            console.log(imagePaths); ============>>>>> Error Line

            res.json("oki");
        })
```

I need to await for loop finish for process. But my output like that:

> [ Promise {  }, Promise {  }, Promise {  }

How Can I solve this problem? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to resolve all the promises in the array with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Promise.all(imagePaths).then(() => {
  res.json("oki")
});
```